# Docker CMD doesn't recognize pm2-runtime

Tags: docker, nginx, pm2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to build a docker image that combines nginx & pm2 but when I'm trying to execute pm2 like [this](https://github.com/keymetrics/docker-pm2/blob/master/example-app/Dockerfile), But when I execute it like that I get following error:

```
/bin/sh: [pm2-runtime,: not found
```

The weird thing is that if I override the CMD and use it like this:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 80:80 frontend-test pm2-runtime
```

It DOES recognize that pm2(-runtime) is installed. Anyone has an idea how this black magic can happen? The previous version I was generating the nuxt pages, and serve them statically via Nginx, but now I want to convert that to using the SSR mode of nuxt. My goal is to run the app and than reverseproxy via Nginx (what seems to work, except that pm2 doesn't want to run). Thanks in advance!

Below is a (little bit simplified) version of my Dockerfile:

```
### BUILD STAGE ###

FROM node:10-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app

# Copy only package(-lock).json to enable docker caching
COPY /index/package*.json /app/index/

# Install packages before copying source code to use cache where possible
WORKDIR /app/index
RUN npm install

# Copy source code
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# Build source code
WORKDIR /app/index
RUN npm run build

### END BUILD STAGE ###

### PRODUCTION STAGE ###

FROM nginx:1.17-alpine as production-stage
ARG env_name=dev

# Install system dependencies (nodejs to run pm2)
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm

# Copy transpiled sourcecode to production image
COPY --from=build-stage /app/index/.nuxt /app/index

# Copy config files to production image
WORKDIR /app
COPY deployment/pm2.js ./ecosystem.config.js
COPY deployment/nginx.${env_name}.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Install pm2 globally
RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN pm2 list

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "--env", ${env_name}, "&&", "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

### END PRODUCTION STAGE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the CMD directive can't handle multiple commands out of the box.

Changing the CMD to following line fixed my issue:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "nginx && pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env $env_name"]
```

Docker CMD & ENTRYPOINT runs the commands implicitly with sh -c, but to chain commands and/or inject environment variables, you need to "nest" the `sh -c` from docker with your own.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are defining the CMD as so

`CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.json" ]`

because from what I see the error message is saying that it's looking for `[pm2-runtime,` (note the `[` at the start and the `,` at the end) and this is possible only if you don't have the quotes around the pm2-runtime. I would suggest you remove and type those quotes again, save the Dockerfile and try building again.

I just tested with a simple example

```
FROM alpine

CMD [echo, "'A'" ]
```

And got a similar error message

```
/bin/sh: [echo,: not found
```

So I am quite certain that this is the case

Comment: Sadly it's not that simple :( I double checked and here is a screenshot of the literal line: https://imgur.com/a/kCn9Ria

Comment: In the screenshot there is no , after the "&&" and it's not the code you provided as the one not working which was this https://github.com/keymetrics/docker-pm2/blob/master/example-app/Dockerfile

Comment: I did provide it in the snippet in my question though. https://imgur.com/a/34dr60j Here a screenshot of the CMD in one line. The comma after "&&" is a good catch though, I'm gonna try that now.

Comment: Still the same. I even deleted every docker image/container and rebuilt without cache... https://imgur.com/a/8xkgdci

Comment: Also, if I just do CMD ["pm2-runtime", "list"] or something like that, I get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you are building that image and then running the same one?
Try

`docker build -t testing . && docker run -it --rm testing`

Comment: And I am quite certain that the issue is with a Dockerfile typo (for example a missing comma or incorrect quotes), because that's the only way I am able to reproduce the exact same error message. 

You can try `docker run -it frontend-test sh` and the try to call that method if that works then I am 100% sure it's the Dockerfile formatting issue

Comment: I applied a linter to it and it said it was valid. I also double checked again, no typo's there.

Comment: @JC97 You’re almost certainly looking at the wrong file. You probably have an old version of the Dockerfile flying around somewhere close by, and `docker build` picks up that one instead of the one you’re currently looking at.

Comment: If I change the CMD to something simple like CMD ["echo", "'A'"], it updates and works. If I change it back to pm2-runtime it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Are you sure it is building the image when you change it to the pm command? I believe that you have a wrong version cached and the build tool doesnt recognize the changes... Try force rebuilding

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on holiday for a couple of days. It's nothing cache related. When I remove  the nginx part of the CMD, it seems to work (altough my pm config is faulty, and I need nginx as well, so it's not a real solution